# JPA mappedBy parent entity returned multiple times same amount as children

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have googled but haven't found proper answer. I use JPA and Spring Data JPA. I have mapped parent table with child table, where the join column is in child table. So in my parent table there is a reference mappedBy and I do the JPA query for the parent entity and instead of it returning only 1, it returns it as many as there are child entities. Here is example:

My tables very simplified

```
Parent

| ID |       COLUMN_A |
|----|----------------|
|  1 | Column A value |
```

---

```
Child
| ID |   CHILD_COLUMN_A | PARENT_ID |
|----|------------------|-----------|
|  1 | Child column A 1 |         1 |
|  2 | Child column A 2 |         1 |
|  3 | Child column A 3 |         1 |
```

Native query I do that return **what i want**:
`SELECT * FROM parent p INNER JOIN child c ON p.id = c.parent_id`

```
| ID |   CHILD_COLUMN_A | PARENT_ID |
|----|------------------|-----------|
|  1 | Child column A 1 |         1 |
|  2 | Child column A 2 |         1 |
|  3 | Child column A 3 |         1 |
```

My entity mappings are following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    List<child> children = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child implements Serializable{
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
        ....
}
```

My annotated query in the ParentRepository class is as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Parent p INNER JOIN FETCH p.children c")
public Collection<Parent> getAll();
```

So with above query I get returned a Collection with **3** `Parent` objects, instead of 1! And in each Parent object is correctly 3 'Child' objects as supposed to be. So question is why does it return `Parent` same amount as it has `Child` in it? I can look at the generated SQL, but it doesn't help me much by just seeing it. Other thing I can add distinct:

`SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Parent p INNER JOIN FETCH p.children c`

but then again, it's not optimized, cause it first gets excessive `Parent` objects with `Child` and then narrows down to one. What if I would have 1000 `Child` objects, then it would produce 1000 `Parent` objects which would be really overwhelming.

I'm sure this is common problem, but I couldn't find anything, there was only Hibernate specific answer to use FetchType.SUBSELECT, but it didn't change results. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword as you described without worrying, because it is the database layer's problem to do that effectively. Also, you might consider removing the `INNER JOIN` with the children if you do not have any conditions in the query (that you did not show).

Comment: Thanks I'll stick to it and will compare the SQL statements created with DISTINCT and without.